# Iconv will be deprecated in the future

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I tried to read an excel file using this code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'parseexcel'
workbook=Spreadsheet::ParseExcel.parse("D:/TEST.xls")
```

and I faced the following error:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead. default formats are encoded in ISO-8859-1
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/parseexcel-0.5.2/lib/parseexcel/olestorage.rb:108:in `initialize': No such file or directory - D:/TEST.xls (Errno::ENOENT)
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/parseexcel-0.5.2/lib/parseexcel/olestorage.rb:108:in `open'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/parseexcel-0.5.2/lib/parseexcel/olestorage.rb:108:in `initialize'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/parseexcel-0.5.2/lib/parseexcel/parser.rb:173:in `new'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/parseexcel-0.5.2/lib/parseexcel/parser.rb:173:in `parse'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/parseexcel-0.5.2/lib/parseexcel/parseexcel.rb:10:in `parse'
from lkc.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

What is the problem, and why can't I read the excel file?

Answer (score 3):

I think the actual error message is this, on the second line:

```
No such file or directory - D:/TEST.xls (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Try `D:\TEST.xls` or `D:\\TEST.xls` instead.

Comment: But i still get this uninitialized constant Spreadsheet (NameError)

Answer (score 1):

The title is misleading, this "Iconv will be deprecated in the future" is not the real issue - it's just a warning. As @brandon-tilley says, the problem is that the file you are trying to open does not exist. Try opening IRB, and typing File.open("D:\Test.xml") etc until you do not get an error message. Then you know the file exists and the path is correct, and you can continue debugging other aspects (if there are still errors).

Comment: Are you insane?  If people started trying things in irb, there'd be no easy questions to answer in stackoverflow...  Lord help us if they ever figure out how to use a debugger or pry.

Comment: But i get this error still uninitialized constant Spreadsheet (NameError). Y this error is coming